# Fixing Creating a Pause Menu in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was following a tutorial from Brackeys on making a pause menu for my game
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JivuXdrIHK0&t=577s
However, when I click ESCAPE, it does open up the menu, however, I can’t click any of the buttons, they don’t work. Do I was wondering if someone could spot any kind of error in the script that I may have made that I've missed, or if you encountered that error before and managed to fix it.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PausedMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static bool GameIsPaused = false;
    public GameObject pauseMenuUI;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
        {
            if (GameIsPaused)
            {
                Resume();
            }
            else
            {
                Pause();
            }
        }
    }

   public void Resume()
   {
       pauseMenuUI.SetActive(false);
       Time.timeScale = 1f;
       GameIsPaused = false;
   }

    void Pause()     
    {
        pauseMenuUI.SetActive(true);
        Time.timeScale = 0f;
        GameIsPaused = true;
    }

    public void LoadMenu()
    {
        Debug.Log("Loading Game...");
    }

    public void QuitGame()
    {
        Debug.Log("Quitting Game...");
    }
}
```

Comment: The script you have there seems fine, maybe the problem is to do with the buttons in the pause menu instead? How are those coded?

Comment: do you have an eventmanager?

Comment: What does `they don’t work` mean? Are they interactive at all (responding to hover/press) or just nothing happens? -> Are the according methods configrued correctly in the Buttons' `OnClick`?

Answer (score -1):

Attach your script to the parent game object. Remove **```** This last line from your code.

Make sure your game object is in this sequence.

[image]

you have to attach your script in PauseCanvas.